# How do I crop an image pulled from the Facebook API for display on a website?

Tags: css, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, crop

I'm using JavaScript and the Facebook Graph API to pull random profile images to a website I'm working on, like so:

```
var image_src = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+newId+"/picture?type=large"
```

However, some of the pictures I'm receiving are very tall. I need to regulate the height by cropping so that images over 350px are removed. The images that are pulled are housed in a DIV like so:

```
<div id = "right-guy"></div>
```

I've tried giving the DIV a max-height in CSS, but that doesn't seem to work. I then tried the CSS "clip" function:

```
#right-guy {
```

margin: 0;
 padding: 50px 30px;
 position: absolute;
 clip:rect(20px,20px,20px,20px);
 overflow: hidden;
 }

But from what I can tell, clip only works on images and not DIV's as a whole, because nothing is happening. Is there a) a way for me to reference the image in CSS despite the fact that the image is not static and is randomly pulled, OR b) crop the DIV once its contents go past a maximum height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work around this problem as well by using image source for a background image of e.g. a link or a div rather than for a real image tag. Something like this:

```
<a class="user-image" href="link/to/users/profile" style="background-image:http://graph.facebook.com/"+newId+"/picture?type=large" title="Visit XY's profile">User name</a>

a.user-image {
    background: transparent no-repeat top left;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could force the div's height, then use `overflow:hidden` in the CSS for that div.  Any child elements large enough to expand the div will be masked by it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually need to crop image your self, Face book can crop image in dimensions you want.

Instead of using - 
var image_src = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+newId+"/picture?type=large"

Use this -
var image_src "http://graph.facebook.com/"+newId+"/picture?width="+width+"&height="+height

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution: http://ajaxray.com/blog/rounded-thumb-image-with-css-3
And the demo: http://ajaxray.com/Examples/cropped-thumb.html

It's just 2 simple steps.

First, in your css, add a class for the link/span that will hold your image.

```
<style type="text/css">
a.user-image {
    background: transparent no-repeat top left;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #666;
}
</style>
```

In HTML, use your image as background-image image of that element.

```
<a class="user-image" href="http://www.facebook.com/ajaxray" style="background-image: url(http://graph.facebook.com/667896332/picture)" title="Visit Anis's profile">Anis Ahmad</a>
```

Comment: Hello @laalto, I've added code sample for this solution. Thanks for your suggestion.